# Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. - Django

Tags: python, django, docker, google-cloud-run

I'm new to asking questions on SO, so bear with me. I know there are a lot of answers about this already, but none of them work. I've been working on making a Django web app, and now I have to deploy it so you can access it on mobile. I've been trying to get it running on Google Cloud Run, but no luck. I've made the Docker container, and that runs fine locally, but when I try to deploy the container, it gives me the following error:
`Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.`

The logs loop back to the same page, with no additional information. I've tried to switch the ports in the docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile to 80, 8000, 8080, and any variation in between, with no luck. I know with Django stuff you're meant to use the App Engine, but I've already loaded too much stuff into the sqlite3 database, and all the sources I can find for the App engine are about PostGres, which I don't have time to convert over to. I also made sure to include the `ALLOWED_HOST 0.0.0.0` in the `settings.py`, so I don't know what's happening.
Here are the contents of my Dockerfile:

```
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
EXPOSE 8080
ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
RUN mkdir /Exeplore
WORKDIR /Exeplore
COPY requirements.txt /Exeplore/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /Exeplore/
```

Here are the contents of my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      MYENV: EXAMPLE
    volumes:
      - .:/code
  web_migrate:
    extends:
      service: web
    command: python manage.py migrate
  web_run:
    extends:
      service: web
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

This is the error I get from google cloud run, and the log just links to the same page:

[image: This is the error I get from google cloud run, and the log just links to the same page]

I hope I've done this right, but please let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: Google Cloud Run does not support Docker Compose configuration files. You must start the web server in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Ah, how would I go about doing that? Thank you for your quick response!

Comment: Review the **CMD** and **ENTRYPOINT** instructions in the Dockerfile documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: So I've now added CMD python manage.py runserver to the bottom of my Dockerfile, and I'm now building it by doing docker build . -t [name of project I assume], and it's now not instantly failing! How long does the health check usually take?

Comment: I take it back, now the docker isn't running locally.

Comment: @JohnHanley I got it to work!! Thank you so much for all your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Add the Docker compose commands to the Dockerfile

```
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
EXPOSE 8080
ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
RUN mkdir /Exeplore
WORKDIR /Exeplore
COPY requirements.txt /Exeplore/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /Explore/
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" "manage.py"]
CMD [ "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8080" ]
```

You should now be able to call the python application with the necessary parameters e.g. to perform the default command.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 my_container
```

In the above Dockerfile:

- The Entrypoint will issue the call to the `python` interpreter and call the `manage.py` application.
- The CMD (command) will call the additional parameters used in the compose file (i.e. `runserver 0.0.0.0:8080`). You can override the default behaviour by adding the necessary parameter i.e. `migrate`.

e.g.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 my_container migrate
```

Comment: I've added what you have suggested, and now Google Cloud Run is reporting it can't find the manage.py file. I've had it run ls, and it's just not there, even though every other file is.

Comment: Hey, apologies I think there is a typo in the above example. Please replace /Exeplore with /Explore. This should make the python script discoverable.

Comment: I've had more of a look, it seems to be another issue with our github. For some reason, the github has split our project into two folders - ExePlore and Exeplore, for no reason. When you download the repo, it is correctly organised (which must be why it correctly runs on my local environment). But since GCR gets it directly from the GitHub, that must be the issue. I've had it print out the files, and it's only adding the files in that arbitrary folder. I have no clue how to fix this, but thank you for your answer, when it gets more repaired, I'll have a look at it!